# Use variable from other fragments

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have 2 classes. I want to stop one class timer from another class.

**Start.class**

```
public class Start extends DialogFragments{
CountDownTimer timer1;
//rest of the code
}
```

**Stop.class**

```
public class Stop extends DialogFragments{
//I want to access the "CountDownTimer timer1;" here.
```

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: How can I declare/use the "CountDownTimer timer1" in the Stop class I try to create a variable but the app crash.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LocalBroadcast or EventBus.
Please write sendBroadcast() in Stop Fragment.
And write BroadcastReceiver in Start Fragment.

Comment: Im new in android environment is there any simple way ? or simple code to  do this

Answer (score 0):

You can create your CountDownTimer object in the activity holding those fragments.
You will get your activity by `getActivity()` and typecast it your activity class. This way you access your CountDownTimer object. Your getActivity object can return null after the fragment is detached from the activity.

Other way simple way is you a singleton class to adn use it both the fragments. this you will not have use your avtivity.